# Redux reducer gets string instead of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to update my state using redux, but for some reason the reducer only gets a string instead of an object.

```
// action    
const switchTab = (activeTab) => { return { type: SWITCH_TAB, activeTab } }

//reducer
const appUIManagement = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case SWITCH_TAB: 
        return Object.assign({}, state, {activeTab: action.activeTab});
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

Assuming my initial state is

```
{activeTab: 'lines'}
```

Now when I dispatch an action:

```
{ type:SWITCH_TAB, { activeTab: 'favorites' } },
```

the state parameter of my reducer is only 'lines' instead of the whole object and because of this my response looks something like

```
{
  activeTab: {
    '0': 'l',
    '1': 'i',
    '2': 'n',
    '3': 'e',
    '4': 's',
    activeTab: 'favorites'
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or what is it that I'm not getting about redux?
Thank you

Comment: You are using action.activeTab in Object.assign, shouldn't it be { activeTab: action.activeTab} ?

Comment: Well that was what I did initially, and that would make sense. But that just creates something like {actionTab: {actionTab: 'test'}}

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the string `action.activeTab` into `Object.assign`

```js
const state = {};
const action = { type: 'SWITCH_TAB', activeTab: 'lines' };
const newState = Object.assign({}, state, action.activeTab);
console.log(newState);
```

However, `Object.assign` expects objects as its arguments so you should pass the whole action or better yet the portion of the action that you need:

```js
const state = {};
const action = { type: 'SWITCH_TAB', activeTab: 'lines' };
const newState = Object.assign({}, state, { activeTab: action.activeTab })
console.log(newState);
```

Comment: Please see my other comment about this

Comment: The solution I proposed above wouldn't lead to doubly nested `{ activeTab: { activeTab } }` result. Did you run the snippets in my answer and saw the results? My approach gives you `{ activeTab: 'lines' }`

Comment: Yes, and if I open up a separate codepen and just put some test objects there then I have the same result. I think my problem is redux specific. Redux passes only the value of the key that changes. Because this is not an object I am running into the problem above.

Comment: So based on the result here's my best guess on what's happening. You have a reducer specific for `activeTab` that updates that state. That state is just a string. This means that you don't even need `Object.assign` and your entire logic of updating the state can be to always set it to the value of `activeTab` like this(without `Object.assign`): `return action.activeTab` will set `state.activeTab` to whatever `action.activeTab` is. It's my guess that right now you are setting `state.activeTab` to `{ activeTab: action.activeTab }` because you're unnecessarily using `Object.assign`

Comment: So in summary, instead of `return Object.assign({}, state, { activeTab: action.activeTab })` just do `return action.activeTab`

Comment: Yes this works. But isn't the redux way to return the current state and change bits of it? Also this way assumes that activeTab is the only thing in the state(which it is in this case, but what if it wasn't?), and then everything else is lost

Comment: redux way is to update the state in an immutable way such that we always return new state. Whether that new state includes anything from the old state is use-case specific. There's no requirement to do so. It just happens to be useful most of the time. As far as your other questions, if the shape of the state changes, then you'll update your reducers accordingly, there's no reason to try and solve problems you don't have yet.